# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, dependencies, chart.js

I've got some javascript code where multiple javascript files and libraries getting loaded.

- chartjs
- chartjs-plugin-datalabels
- chartjs-plugin-datatables

In most cases there is no problem with loading these files.

But sometimes I get an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined'

I think that sometimes Chart.js is not completely loaded. So how do I make sure, that Chart.js is loaded and then load my dependent scripts?

The error is thrown by chartjs-plugin-datalabels:

```
chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js?_=1570176417056:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined
    at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js?_=1570176417056:15
    at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js?_=1570176417056:10
    at chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js?_=1570176417056:11
```

This is how I load all my javascript files:

```
Promise.all([loadChartJS(), loadOtherScripts(), loadCss()])
    .then(() => {
        //do something with loaded files.
    });




function loadChartJS() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dependentScripts = [
            libs/chartjs.min.js,
            libs/someLib.js,
            libs/anotherLib.js,
        ];
        for (var i in dependentScripts) {
            $.getScript(dependentScripts[i]).done(function(script, textStatus) {
                resolve();
            })
        }

    });
}

function loadScripts() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        listOfScripts = [
            libs/datatables.min.js,
            libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js,
             ... some other files
        ];

        var stage = 0;
        for (let e in listOfScripts) {
            $.getScript(listOfScripts[e])
                .done(function(script, textStatus) {
                    stage++;
                    if (stage == listOfScripts.length) {
                        resolve();
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                    reject(jqxhr);
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in both cases you are resolving the single Promises when the first element in `dependentScripts` and `listOfScripts`are loaded and not when all of them are loaded. I.e., you are not waiting for all the `dependentScripts` and `listOfScripts` before resolving the Promise.

Comment: I've tried to resolve the promises when `stage == listOfScripts.length` as you can see above. I also changed this approach in `loadChartJS`. It seemed to work. But the error occured randomly again.
Is it recommended to use requirejs or webpack in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution for loading dependent scripts in my case.
So the plugin DataLabels is only loaded when chartjs is resolved.

```
$.when(
    $.getScript(`libs/chartjs.min.js`),
    $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        $(deferred.resolve);
    })
).done(function() {
    $.getScript(`libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js`)
    //Load other scripts
    Promise.all([loadScripts(), loadCss()])
        .then(() => {

            //do stuff ...

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

we have two file 1. `chart.js` and 2. `datalabels.plugins` these two files enough for create different types of charts and `datalabels` plugins responsible for labels of data so that first attach your file `"chartjs"` and after `datalabels` plugins. So first load `chartjs` and then any plugins.